# How to read commands from a file in npm script

Tags: node.js, package.json

What I have:

```
"scripts": {    
      "postinstall": "prisma migrate deploy; prisma generate; … <and the line goes on forever>
```

is there some way for `scripts` to read the commands from a file? In a way that each line would be executed like `npm <line>`? Or even if all commands was on one line?

I could of course stick them in an executable `postinstall.sh` and run with npx or something, but it isn't very "cross-platform friendly" and 2) would need npx installed too...

This is just to avoid having super long lines in package.json, to try and keep it cleaner.